# Adding an object to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a personal movie database with Javascript where I can add movies, directors, actors, etc. And then search for them in different ways (for example if type in "Spielberg" it would present a list of the movies where Spielberg has been named as the director).

The beginner I am I ran into a problem immediately.

```js
//I created an array which is supposed to store all the data
let movieList = [];

//Then I tried to create constructor function which I would use again and again to add movies to my list

function Movie() {
  this.name = prompt("Movie name?", "-");
  this.year = prompt("Movie year?", "-");
  this.director = prompt("Movie director?", "-");
  this.actor = prompt("Movie actor?", "-");
}

//After I fill in the information I am supposed to add the object into my array
movieList.push(Movie);

console.log(movieList);
```

Well, it does not work at all. Even the prompts dont work. Obviously there is a problem with the code functionality, but also if you have any input whether I am approaching this the correct way (using an array, constructor function) in the first place, I would appreacite it.

Not a native English speaker, sorry for the typos.

Comment: you need to push an object not the constructor function. try `var movie = new Movie()`

Comment: your movie function needs to return the object

Comment: You need to [construct](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) the object. That’s why it’s a constructor. `movieList.push(new Movie());`.

Comment: @Grambam A constructor returns the newly constructed object by default.

Comment: Calling `prompt()` from a constructor sounds SOOOO WROOOOONG! Please just use four text fields and an "Add movie" button.

Comment: Even after you get things "right" in your code: the fun will not last for very long! Your front end code can at best store that data in your browser's memory (local storage). But without some kind of backend you will not be able to build a database together with other users.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't mind me demonstrating a slightly more user-friendly version of your input routine. With a form (instead of `prompt()`) the user can decide the order in which they want to input their information:

```js
const movieList = [], 
 props="name,year,director,actor".split(",");
movie.onsubmit=ev=>{
 ev.preventDefault();
 movieList.push(Object.fromEntries(props.map(p=>[p,movie[p].value])));
 console.log(movieList);
}
```

```html
<form name="movie">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Movie name?"><br>
<input type="text" name="year" placeholder="Year?"><br>
<input type="text" name="director" placeholder="Director?"><br>
<input type="text" name="actor" placeholder="Actor?"><br>
<button>add movie</button>
</form>
```

I omitted creating a class with constructor and all the trimmings. The movie objects are created directly with `Object.fromEntries()` on the basis of an array that consists of key-value pairs.